# Has vimeo.com supported IPV6? And what's the IPV6 address of vimeo?

Tags: ipv6, vimeo

I'd like to access vimeo (http://vimeo.com/) by ipv6, but what is its ipv6 address?

Comment: This question is not related to Stack Overflow, and shows poor research effort on the questioner's part.

Answer (score 4):

Obviously (as you can do via a simple DNS request), they don't have an IPv6 address:

```
$ host -a vimeo.com
Trying "vimeo.com"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 16587
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 10, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 7

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;vimeo.com.                     IN      ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
vimeo.com.              30      IN      TXT     "v=spf1 a mx ptr ip4:74.113.232.150 ip4:74.113.232.149 include:iac.com -all"
vimeo.com.              30      IN      MX      6 vimeo.com.s7b2.psmtp.com.
vimeo.com.              30      IN      MX      6 vimeo.com.s7b1.psmtp.com.
vimeo.com.              30      IN      MX      6 vimeo.com.s7a2.psmtp.com.
vimeo.com.              30      IN      NS      ns4.iaccap.com.
vimeo.com.              30      IN      SOA     primary.vimeo.com. admin.vimeo.com. 2008102362 86400 7200 604800 300
vimeo.com.              30      IN      NS      ns1.iaccap.com.
vimeo.com.              30      IN      MX      6 vimeo.com.s7a1.psmtp.com.
vimeo.com.              30      IN      NS      ns2.iaccap.com.
vimeo.com.              30      IN      A       74.113.233.128

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
vimeo.com.s7a1.psmtp.com. 14359 IN      A       64.18.6.10
vimeo.com.s7b2.psmtp.com. 14359 IN      A       64.18.6.14
vimeo.com.s7b1.psmtp.com. 14359 IN      A       64.18.6.13
ns4.iaccap.com.         86400   IN      A       74.113.238.28
ns1.iaccap.com.         86400   IN      A       74.113.232.28
vimeo.com.s7a2.psmtp.com. 14359 IN      A       64.18.6.11
ns2.iaccap.com.         86400   IN      A       66.235.119.14
```